# Labelling line with angles from 0º to 360º in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, line, geometry-generator, angles

Labelling lines with the following function:

```
round(degrees(atan2(yat(-1)-yat(0), xat(-1)-xat(0))), 1) || ' º'
```

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, this expression calculates the orientation angle of the lines. From 0º to 180º degrees I can interpret the angle. However, from 180º to 360º it seems that the expression replicates the orientation angle in a negative value from 0 to -180.

What correction should I make so that the degrees from 180º to 360º are represented?

Comment: The output range of the `atan2` function is from -pi to +pi. Add 360 if your value is negative.

Comment: Solved. I add a reply with the solution I have found related to this comment

Comment: @IngridIngravida, please put your *Proposed solution* as a valid answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Proposed solution**

According to the comment of the user [Vince](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/21577/vince), I have modified my expression in the following sense to obtain the positive angles from 0º to 360º:

```sql
CASE
    WHEN round(degrees(atan2(yat(-1)-yat(0),xat(-1)-xat(0))),1) > 0
    THEN round(degrees(atan2(yat(-1)-yat(0),xat(-1)-xat(0))),1)
    ELSE 360 + round(degrees(atan2(yat(-1)-yat(0),xat(-1)-xat(0))),1)
END
```

[image: screenshot of the result]

Comment: You might be able to cut a corner in the complexity of your `WHEN` by just comparing the Y components. If y2 is less than y1, it's going to be in quadrants III or IV (note that this might flip some rounded values)